# .filter(':last') vs. .last()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, filter

I was wondering if there is any difference between `.filter(':last')` and `.last()`?

For me it looks like they're doing the same, but I'm new to jQuery. If there is no difference in the result, which one is recommended or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: They do the same thing, and for most cases you''ll never notice the difference.

Comment: The first one operates on all elements, running a non-standard selector against each one. The second one just grabs the last element from the jQuery object, and returns it in a new object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`last` works by saying "give me the last element from the selection". It takes just two function calls and four lines of code to do so. It can't be done in a quicker way.

`filter(':last')`, however, is much more complex. It is a much more flexible system, allowing multiple elements to be returned if that's what you want, or multiple conditions, or a mixture of both. It is much less efficient, because it has to work out what you want. For instance, parsing `':last'` takes a little time, whereas with the `last` function it's a simple property lookup.

`last` is by far the more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

> [**`:last`**](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) - Selects the last matched element.
>
> [**`last()`**](http://api.jquery.com/last/) - Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

As you can see, they do the same thing (in terms of the end result, anyway).

`last()` [**is slightly faster than :last**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-last-selector-vs-last-method) (although you may not notice it, it's always good to know).

**[`.filter(":last")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**, although making the best (performance-wise) out of `:last`, still involves more function calls and is still slower than `last()` - although it does have its advantages (see [@lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17076315/1586880)'s answer for those).

My recommendation however would be to generally use `last()` as opposed to the former.